# Counting inversions in an array of 1 to N

Tags: algorithms

Is there a straightforward way to characterise the number of inversions in an array of length `N` having distinct elements, each element an integer from 1 to `N`?

It's for a constraint optimization problem, where the number of inversions needs to be minimized.

Comment: In order to avoid the XY problem, it should be helpful to explain that constraint optimization problem. Or, at least, provide an accessible reference to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can count inversions efficiently by adapting mergesort, but the most intuitive way is to just count all pairs:

$$\text{inv}(A) = \sum_{i=1}^{|A|}\sum_{j=i+1}^{|A|}[A_j<A_i]$$

Where $[A_j < A_i] = 1$ when $A_j < A_i$ and $0$ otherwise.